# Change Wallpaper intent Application crashes in Nook Color:

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper, nook

I need to develop a Wallpaper application for Nook Color. I have installed the Nook color addon after that when i use this code in my app and it gets crashed every time. The below API Intent to allow any application to open the Wallpaper Settings Manager UI in Nook Color device

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction( "com.bn.nook.CHANGE_WALLPAPER" );
startActivity( i );

Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.bn.nook.CHANGE_WALLPAPER }
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: is "com.bn.nook.CHANGE_WALLPAPER" an Activity in your application or one on the Nook?

Comment: I referred a Nook developer site to do this. Please see this link https://onnook.org/

Answer (score 1):

This intent is only going to be available on Nook device.

Using this on any other device or emulator that isn't specifically designed to be the nook isn't going to work.

It would be like trying to open Internet Explorer on a machine which doesn't have Internet Explorer installed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is a direct copy paste from (i assume) the official Nook Developer page [here](http://onnook.org/2011/06/15/nook-api-open-wallpaper-settings-ui/).

The code isn't inherently wrong, the Action your specifying simply doesn't seem to exist - you need to find the correct Action name from the Developers/Nook API.

Comment: No, my code works only in Nook device but it crashes in all simulators  and non nook devices